# Ruby on Rails : add a new route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new with RoR so this is a newbie question:
if I have a controller `users_controller.rb` and I add a method `foo`, shouldn't it create this route?

> http://www.localhost:3000/users/foo

because when I did that, I got this error:

> Couldn't find User with id=foo

I of course added a view `foo.html.erb`

**EDIT:**
I added to `routes.rb` this code but I get the same error:

```
resources :users do
    get "signup"
  end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This doesn't work automatically  in rails 3.  You'll need to add

```
resource :users do
    get "foo"
end
```

to your routes.rb

You'll definitely want to have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, it explains routing pretty well.

Comment: actually it didn't help. for some reason I still get the same message

Comment: Try restarting your app.  Route changes requite a restart.

Comment: didn't help. weird, isn't it?

Comment: What do you get when you run rake routes?

Answer (score 6):

Rails is directing you to the show controller and thinks that you're providing foo as :id param to the show action.

You need to set a route that will be dispatched prior to being matched as /users/:id in users#show

You can accomplish this by modifying `config/routes.rb` by adding the following to replace your existing resource describing `:users`

```
resource :users do
    get "foo"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other answers, in earlier versions of Rails there used to be a default route

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

which gave the behaviour you describe where a request of the form *controller/action* would call the given method on the given controller. This line is still in `routes.rb` but is commented out by default. You can uncomment it to enable this behaviour but the comment above it explains why this is not recommended:

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
```

Comment: Please don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

At the schema `':controller/:action(.:format)'`, you can also easily do the following

```
resources :users do
   get "foo", on: :collection
end
```

or

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'foo'
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes